# How do I handle rate limiting in the Dropbox API?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, httplib

The Dropbox API docs state that in the event of being rate limited, a 503 HTTP status code will be returned, with a "Retry-After" header. However, in what I suspect is a case of rate limiting, this is the actual reponse I get:

```
[503] Error parsing response body or headers: Body - '\r\n<html>\r\n<head><title>Dropbox 
- 5xx</title>\r\n<link href="https://www.dropbox.com/static/css/ Headers - {'transfer-
encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'nginx', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'cache-control': 
'no-cache', 'date': 'Sat, 31 May 2014 12:55:40 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html'}
```

(Actually this is the `str(e)` of `dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse as e`)

There is no Retry-After header, so this may not be a case of rate limiting. If that's the case then I don't know what this error is telling me.

Does anyone have an example of an actual rate-limiting response that I can test against?

Answer (score 2):

The response just indicates some random server glitch. You should try the request again. As you've indicated, this scenario is documented in the *Standard API Errors* section of the [Core API Reference](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs):

> **503**
>
> If the response includes the `Retry-After` header, this means your ... app is being rate limited. Otherwise, this indicates a transient server error, and your app should retry its request.

Comment: Agreed that this is *not* rate limiting.